# AJAX POST JSON to .NET Webservice gives 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, web-services

I am trying to consume a .NET webservice with AJAX and want a JSON response. Everything works fine. I have used fiddler and get the appropriate Json returnet. also using the plain URL in the browser gives the appropriate XML.

Even using PHP Curl gives me the right JSON in response but when i am trying to use AJAX i get a "500 Internal Server Error".

Any help appriciated, Thanks.

```
<script>        
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:9000/APIs/BuyVoucherService.asmx/HelloWorld",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            },
        error: function(data){
        alert(data);
        }
     });
});  
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you POSTing? When you visit the page in your browser, that is a GET. Try changing the type to GET. Also, post the full body of the 500 error.

Comment: when getting JSON from a .asmx webservice you have to use POST and contentType application/json or else it will simply return XML

Comment: The problem i have realized is that this wont work because of cross domian issues. the solution to get the AJAX call to work with a cross domain solution is to use JSONP. http://www.json-p.org/ for more information

Comment: obviously the error is coming from the server side. Could you show the Web Method.

Comment: yes it is a serverside error. the problem is as i said that the service and site are hosted on different domains. therefore i am forced to use JSON-P if i want the AJAX to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem i have realized is that this wont work because of cross domian issues. the solution to get the AJAX call to work with a cross domain solution is to use JSONP. http://www.json-p.org/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have omitted a data definition in your request, try to add something like this:

```
data: "{}",
```

Comment: i omitted the data: "{}" because i somply dident want to sen any data. but i get the same result with data: "{}" or data: {}. i have solved the problem but unfortunatley i cant answer my own question yet. The solution is in the comments of OP. JSON-P is needed because of cross domian issues